# How can I add a new block over footer?Magento

Tags: php, html, xml, magento

I have this page:

[link](http://s1.busteco.ro/frontend/cristi/)

I want to put an h1 tag as in the picture below.

[image]

In file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`

I added the following **code XML**

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>

                <block type="page/test2" name="test" as="test" template="page/test2/test.phtml"></block> //here is my modification

                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="*" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
                </block>
                <!-- This static block can be created and populated in admin. The footer_links cms block can be used as a starting point. -->
                <!--<block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_links">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_social_links</block_id></action>
                </block>-->
            </block>
```

Then we created an **PHTML** file I put in location

```
page/test2/test.phtml
```

**CODE FOR PHTML FILE**

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

I want to do something as simple as learning to use block sites.

Can you please tell me what is good and what should correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: create your own theme instead of modifying core files, see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html. And the problem with your code is your block type, try the `core/template` block:

```
<block type="core/template" name="test" as="test" template="page/test2/test.phtml"></block>
```

And when you're done testing, use some realistic names.